# Trouble with .csv and floats

Tags: python, list, csv, heatmap

As a learning project I am generating a heat map of traffic accidents. I have a .csv file that has the latitude and longitude of all intersections, as well as the number of accidents at each intersection. What I need is a list containing all the latitude-longitude pairs for every accident.

e.g. 
2,1.2,4.2
2,2.2,5.2
2,3.2,6.2

becomes: [(1.2,4.2), (1.2,4.2), (2.2,5.2), (2.2,5.2), (3.2,6.2), (3.2,6.2)]

Here is the code I have:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lat = []
    lon = []
    num = []

    for row in reader:
        num.append(row[0])
        lat.append(row[1])
        lon.append(row[2])

    def prep(a,b):
        d = [str(x)*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
        for i in d:
            d = [list(i) for i in d]
        d = sum(d, [])
        d = [int(i) for i in d]
        return d

    e = zip(prep(lat, num), prep(lon, num))

    for i in e:
         print "new google.maps.LatLng", i, ","
```

I tested the function with lists containing integers and it worked fine; however, it does not seem to like floats. Here is the error message I get:

```
d = [str(x)*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]<br/>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Does anyone know of a solution as I have spent 2 days tinkering/Googling.

Comment: write your list comprehension out in long form and think about why you would want to use a string 'str(x)' in a multiplication operation when traditionally numbers are used for that. Perhaps str(x*y) is what you want.

Comment: Do you simply want to count how many incidents happened at a given intersection?

Comment: You could append directly the numbers the way you wanted, to the final list, without getting number/latitude/longitude and then working on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using just a list comprehension expression and `itertools.chain`?

```
>>> l1=(2,1.2,4.2)
>>> l2=(2,2.2,5.2)
>>> l3=(2,3.2,6.2)
>>> l=[l1,l2,l3]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[[(j,k) for t in range(i)]for i,j,k in l]))
[(1.2, 4.2), (1.2, 4.2), (2.2, 5.2), (2.2, 5.2), (3.2, 6.2), (3.2, 6.2)]
```

Comment: Fantastic! I had never read about intertools.chain before. I appreciate the solution; this is proving to be a good project for learning.

Comment: why are you calling list inside the list?

Comment: @ziltoid you're welcome , yep `itertools` is a knight in python data structures modules !

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i have forget it ! i edit the answer , thanks for reminding !

Comment: actually no reason whatsoever to use itertools here

Answer (score 1):

If you just want pairs it is pretty trivial:

```
with open('in.txt','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print [tuple(map(float,row[1:])) for row in reader for _ in xrange(int(row[0]))]
[(1.2, 4.2), (1.2, 4.2), (2.2, 5.2), (2.2, 5.2), (3.2, 6.2), (3.2, 6.2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is clear: You can't multiply a str by a str, i.e. you have not converted the strings to floats or ints.

Because your approach is very hard to unterstand, I suggest to use list comprehension to make what you want in an easier and more understandable way:

```
with open('file.csv','rb') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    e = [(float(lon), float(lat)) for num, lat, lon in reader for i in range(int(num))]        
    for i in e: 
        print "new google.maps.LatLng", i, ","
```